# PYQT emit touch signal to another class class cannot receive parameters

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to capture the Touch event in class Touch and then use pyqtsignal emit signal to class test, but the abc function of class test is not receive at all,

This program comes from
https://github.com/XiaoshuaiGeng/Gameshop-GSMS/blob/b503f9234bf4d1fc38cb3ab0a7c32b506e60a9e4/text1.py

The following is the code I modified

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class Touch(QMainWindow):

    td = pyqtSignal(str)    
   
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Touch, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Capture Touch Event')
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)
        self.move(100, 300)               
     

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):

        if event.type() == QEvent.TouchBegin:      
            print('touch down')
            self.td.emit(str('Down_Pass'))
            return True
            
        elif event.type() == QEvent.TouchEnd:          
            print('touch up')
            self.td.emit(str('Up_Pass'))
            return True

        return super(Touch, self).eventFilter(obj, event)  

class test():       
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = Touch()    
        self.a.td.connect(self.abc)        
               
    def abc(self,x):
        # no show anything
        print(x)                   
        print("1236456")

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window2 = Touch()       
    window2.setAttribute(Qt.WA_AcceptTouchEvents, True)    
    window2.installEventFilter(window2)
    window2.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Right now it's completely impossible to understand your issue, because, based on your code: 1. you never installed any event filter, so `eventFilter()` wouldn't **never** be called; 2. we don't know how the `test` instance is created (assuming any instance actually is). Please provide a **valid** [mre].

Comment: i fix code , minimal reproducible is ok

Comment: `abc` would never be called since you are not creating **any** instance of `test`, and nothing is connected to the `td` signal anyway. Besides, installing an event filter on the same instance is quite pointless: just override [`event()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#event).

Comment: How to fix it . I'm really not good at this part

Comment: Then I strongly suggest you to take your time and do more research about basic OOP aspects like objects, classes, instances, attributes and methods. That `test` is a class (and, as such, should also have a capitalized name), declaring it is completely useless until you *use* it, which normally happens by *explicitly* using its attributes (in this case, its `abc` method) and by creating an instance of it. Objects don't work together just by "magic": something has to use the reference of that `abc` method. Sorry, but StackOverflow is not a tutorial website: you have to find that out on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you are trying to capture the Touch event in your first class (`Touch`) and emit a signal to your other class `test` (remember to use capitalized name. I recommend you to check out the [Style Guide for python code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/). I will replace your `test` class into `Test`).

The main problem of your code is that you are not creating an instance of `test` class so is not connected to the td signal.

Here is a code that should work:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class Touch(QMainWindow):
    td = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Touch, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Capture Touch Event')
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)
        self.move(100, 300)
        
        self.test = Test(parent=self)
        self.td.connect(self.test.abc)
     
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.TouchBegin:      
            print('touch down')
            self.td.emit(str('Down_Pass'))
            return True
        elif event.type() == QEvent.TouchEnd:          
            print('touch up')
            self.td.emit(str('Up_Pass'))
            return True

        return super(Touch, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

class Test(QObject):
    td = pyqtSignal(str)
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.td.connect(self.abc)   
               
    def abc(self,x):
        print(x)                   
        print("1236456")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window2 = Touch()
    window2.setAttribute(Qt.WA_AcceptTouchEvents, True)
    window2.installEventFilter(window2)
    window2.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you want to try with the mouse click and release event you can replace the code inside the `eventFilter` with this one:

```
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            print('touch down')
            self.td.emit(str('Down_Pass'))
            return True
            
        elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
            print('touch up')
            self.td.emit(str('Up_Pass'))
            return True

        return super(Touch, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```